# Force cache reset with MARS enabled and cache in asp.net web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, wcf, caching

There was a problem while working with the data. The changed data in the database is not displayed correctly, because it is cached. I thought it was a problem in the configuration of [WCF services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/caching-support-for-wcf-web-http-services), but after analyzing the configuration files, I realized that service caching was turned off, but the [MARS EF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/enabling-multiple-active-result-sets) function was enabled.

> **MARS Session Cache**
>
> When a connection is opened with MARS enabled, a logical session is
>   created, which adds additional overhead. *To minimize overhead and
>   enhance performance, SqlClient caches the MARS session within a
>   connection.*

The first and the simplest option is to disable this function in the connection setup, but this procedure will take a long time, because in my projects not one service is used. Therefore, the question arose, how can this problem be solved? Can I update the data forcibly? Or somehow reset the cache from the front-end?

> **Stack of technologies:** AngularJS + ASP.NET Web API(WCF).

Service configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, Default Command Timeout=300" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding closeTimeout="00:05:00" openTimeout="00:05:00" sendTimeout="00:05:00" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" /> 
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>

  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MP" connectionString="data source=*;initial catalog=*;user id=*;password=*;application name=*;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Connect Timeout=300" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

WebApi configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <machineKey decryptionKey="*" validation="*" validationKey="*" />
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>

  <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>

  </system.webServer>

  <system.serviceModel>

    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_*" sendTimeout="00:05:00" maxBufferSize="200000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="200000000"/>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_*" sendTimeout="00:05:00" maxBufferSize="200000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="200000000" />
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_*" sendTimeout="00:05:00" maxBufferSize="2000000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="2000000000" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://*" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_*" contract="*" name="*" />
      <endpoint address="http://*" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_*" contract="*" name="*" />
      <endpoint address="http://*" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_*" contract="*" name="*" />
      </client>

  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19578467/entity-framework-affect-of-multipleactiveresultsets-on-caching), but I would like to try to solve the problem in a different way.
I will be glad to any ideas and advice.

**Example of caching in the code:**

Cache.cs:

```
public class CardRegistrationPartyCache
{
    #region Private Members

    private IUserSessionService _userSessionService = null;

    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    public CardRegistrationPartyCache(IUserSessionService userSessionService)
    {
        _userSessionService = userSessionService;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Public

    public void AddOrUpdate(CardRegistrationParty crp)
    {
        string key = this.GetType().FullName + crp.BarcodeID.ToString();
        _userSessionService.SetUserData(key, crp);
    }

    public CardRegistrationParty Get(int barcodeID)
    {
        string key = this.GetType().FullName + barcodeID.ToString();
        return _userSessionService.UserData<CardRegistrationParty>(key);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Realization:

```
public class CardRegistrationPartyService : ApplicationService
{
    #region Constructors

    public CardRegistrationPartyService(IInfrastructureFactory infrastructureFactory)
        : base(infrastructureFactory)
    {

    }

    #endregion

    public IEnumerable<CardRegistrationParty> GetCardRegistrationPartyListWithChecks(IList<KeyValuePair<int, GPF>> list)
    {
        int listCount = list == null ? 0 : list.Count();
        Infrastructure.Logger.Info(String.Format("Get informations (" + listCount.ToString()) + ")");

        // Caching
        CardRegistrationPartyCache cache = new CardRegistrationPartyCache(Infrastructure.CreateUserSessionService());

        IList<CardRegistrationParty> CardRegistrationPartyes = new List<CardRegistrationParty>();

        // Check cache
        foreach(KeyValuePair<int, GPF> item in list)
        {
            CardRegistrationParty party = cache.Get(item.Key);
            if (party != null)
            {
                CardRegistrationPartyes.Add(party);
            }                
        }
        // Delete the keys for which information was found
        if (CardRegistrationPartyes != null)
        {
            foreach (CardRegistrationParty p in CardRegistrationPartyes)
            {
                KeyValuePair<int, GPF> key = new KeyValuePair<int, GPF>(p.BarcodeID, p.Gpf);
                list.Remove(key);
            }                
        }

        // If there are keys on which there was no information - we load
        if ((list != null) &&(list.Count() > 0))
        {
            IEnumerable<CardRegistrationPartyDTO> CardRegistrationPartyesDTO = Infrastructure.CreateTestsOfEriService().GetCardRegistrationPartyListWithChecks(list.Select(m => m.Key).ToArray());

            Infrastructure.Logger.Trace(String.Format("Start DTOs -> DomainObjects"));

            foreach (CardRegistrationPartyDTO CardRegistrationPartyDTO in CardRegistrationPartyesDTO)
            {
                CardRegistrationPartyBuilder cardRegistrationPartyBuilder = new CardRegistrationPartyBuilder(CardRegistrationPartyDTO, list);
                CardRegistrationParty CardRegistrationParty = cardRegistrationPartyBuilder.Build();
                CardRegistrationPartyes.Add(CardRegistrationParty);

                cache.AddOrUpdate(CardRegistrationParty);
            }

            Infrastructure.Logger.Trace(String.Format("End DTOs -> DomainObjects"));
        }

        return CardRegistrationPartyes;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your speculation that MARS is somehow related to caching is probably not correct.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, And with what it can be connected? Because the data after a while starts to be displayed correctly. Or is it due to a local browser cache?

Comment: I have no idea, but it's probably not related to MARS.

Comment: Probably a problem in your code somewhere.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, most likely you are right, could you help me to understand (supplemented information in the question)?

Comment: It looks like you're caching data in the session, and if data is in the cache it will never be updated from the database.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, The data is simply taken from the database, they do not change in the current application. My application simply displays data from the database.